# What's the minimum I should install in oreder to be able to run/create a web service with c#?

Tags: c#

I have visual c#  express installed. Is ther a plug-in like? Must I have all of the .net framework?

Theanks.

Comment: Technically, you could uninstall everything - get the mono source code, strip out everything you don't need and build your own slimmed down mono famework to write against. Would it be worth it? Absolutely not

Answer (score 2):

You will definitely need all of the .net framework. It won't "overload" your system. It just sits there on your hard-drive until you use it. If you installed vc# express, it should be installed already. Technically, you need nothing else. Look up "[self hosted wcf](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=self%20hosted%20wcf)".

Comment: I'm used to work in a multy frameworks env', and several IDE's concurrently. Don't wan't to "abuse" my RAM (2GB) and work slowly.
I have .Net framework SP 2 / 3 / 4 client profile / 4 multy targeting pack.
What can I uninstall?

Comment: Why do you think this is 'abusing' your RAM? If you don't use it, it will just sit there. They are just libraries.

Comment: What @TomW said, and... If your amount of RAM is affecting your productivity, I'd consider buying more RAM.

Comment: "Abusing my RAM" = abusing me due to inefficient work proccess ( CPU's crawling when I use several IDEs )

Comment: My Microsoft visual c# doesn't support web applications . No ASP.net. What should I download? (VB is not neccesary to me, so visual studio is not an option..)

Comment: A self hosted wcf service can run in a console app or a service. No asp.net required. Did you read any of the links in the search I provided?

Comment: If you're worried about Visual Studio consuming too many system resources, you could install it on a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need .NET Framework to create webservices